# How to mock service function in Angular component for unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am writing unit test for angular app, I am testing if the service function  returns a value.

**component.spec.ts**

```
import {TopToolBarService} from '../../top-toolbar/top-toolbar.service';

beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule ({
   declarations: [ UsersListComponent],
   providers: [TopToolBarService],//tried mocking service here,still test failed
   schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
 })
  .compileComponents();
}));



beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });



  it('should return data from service function', async(() => {
    let mockTopToolBarService: jasmine.SpyObj<TopToolBarService>;
    mockTopToolBarService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TopToolBarService', ['getCustomer']);
    mockTopToolBarService.getCustomer.and.returnValue("king");
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.bDefine).toBe(true); //fails
  }))
```

**component.ts**

```
bDefine = false;
ngOnInit() {
 let customer = this.topToolBarService.getCustomer();
 if (customer == null) {
   bDefine = false;
 } else {
    bDefine = true;
   }
}
```

I believe I have mocked the service function in my test, so I expect it must have reached else part where variable is set to 'true'.

**TopToolBarService.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class TopToolBarService {
customer = null;

  getCustomer() {
    return this.customer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably on StackBlitz or similar? What is the rest of `component.spec.ts` and `component.ts`?

Answer (score 45):

Try updating providers inside `beforeEach(async(() => ...)` and moving your `mockedService` variable on the top of it:

```
describe('Component TEST', () => {
   ...
   let mockToolBarService;
   ...
      beforeEach(async(() => {
      ...
      mockToolBarService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getCustomer']);
      mockToolBarService.getCustomer.and.returnValue('king');
      TestBed.configureTestingModule ({
           ...
           providers: [ { provide: TopToolBarService, useValue: mockToolBarService } ]
           ...
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 18):

Change your provider value

```
beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UsersListComponent],
      providers: [{
         provide: TopToolBarService,
         useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('TopToolBarService', ['getCustomer'])
      }],
      schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
     });
     mockTopToolBarService = TestBed.get(TopToolBarService);

     mockTopToolBarService.getCustomer.and.returnValue(of([])); // mock output of function
   })
```

Comment: I have a question, why you used providers?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed sorry, can't tell now, it was more than 3 years ago. I haven't worked on frontend for while now.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider usage of [ng-mocks](http://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) to avoid all that boilerplate to configure `TestBed`.

```js
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(UsersListComponent)
  .mock(TopToolBarService, {
    // adding custom behavior to the service
    getCustomer: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue('king'),
  })
);

it('should return data from service function', () => {
  const fixture = MockRender(UsersListComponent);
  // now right after the render the property should be true
  expect(fixtur.point.componentInstance.bDefine).toBe(true);
}));
```

Comment: How to mock the custom pipe using ng-mock , any example ?

Comment: There is `MockPipe` function: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockPipe

Comment: Why we combined ng-mocks and jasmine.createSpy()?

Comment: `ng-mocks` allows you to customize only what you want, for example `getCustomer` only. So you don't need to mock other dependencies if they exist.

Comment: What's the advantage of including ng-mocks here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the testing module before you run your code. It doesn't know about your spy object unless you pass it to the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` as an import.

https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency

Comment: link broken, update to https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency