# Spec has no expectations when unit testing a Service in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, karma-jasmine

So my tests are passing but it's this one unit test named `should get the notes` for the `NoteService` which, when `ng test` is ran, its name in Karma is written like

> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should get the notes

The method that I am trying to test is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class NoteService {

  readonly baseUrl = "https://localhost:4200";
  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
  };

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 
  getNotes(): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Note[]>(this.baseUrl + `/notes`, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

And the unit test is this:

```
describe('NoteService', () => {
  let service: NoteService;
  
  const mockList = [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "title": "First note",
      "description": "This is the description for the first note",
      "categoryId": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "title": "Second note",
      "description": "This is the description for the first note",
      "categoryId": "2"
    }]

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
      providers: [NoteService]});
    service = TestBed.inject(NoteService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get the notes', fakeAsync(() => {
    service.getNotes().subscribe((val) => {
      expect(val).toBe(mockList);
    });
  }));
});
```

Therefore, why is it saying that "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS"? Is it something wrong with my unit test? And how should I tweak it in order to make it work well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `fakeAsync` here. You should be using `done()` to tell the test it's been finished:

```
it('should get the notes',((done: DoneFN) => {
    service.getNotes().subscribe((val) => {
        expect(val).toBe(mockList);
        done();
    });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is, I was using `done()` previously but gave me this error: `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`. Hence, I changed it to `fakeAsync` after digging up some answers. Therefore, how can I fix that timeout error that `done()` gives me?

Comment: You have to mock `service.getNotes()` before and make it return an Observable.

Comment: Thanks once again. Think you could help me out with an advice on how to do that? I am not sure if I should get rid of `TestBed` completely as shown in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331328/how-to-mock-service-function-in-angular-component-for-unit-test

Comment: try `spyOn(service, 'getNotes').and.returnValue(of(val))`